# I get BAD REQUEST when attempting me/accounts

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

here is what i have been able to accomplish:

1.) redirect to get permissions and to login

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APPID&redirect_uri=MYURL&scope=manage_pages,publish_stream

2.) get access token for user

```
QString = "client_id=" & APPID &  "redirect_uri="  & MYURL & "&client_secret=" & APPSEC & "&code=" & Auth_Code
bytArguments = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("")
bytRetData = oWeb.UploadData("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" & QString, "POST", bytArguments)
Access_Code = Split(Split(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytRetData), "&")(0), "=")(1)
```

here is where i get stumped with a 400 bad request:

I go to access the account for the user...which will only really be myself...and i get a 400 BAD REQUEST error.

```
bytArguments = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("access_token=" & Access_Code)
Uri = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts"
bytRetData = oWeb.UploadData(Uri, "POST", bytArguments)
results = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytRetData)
```

With this said...WHAT AM I DOING WRONG???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing a HTTP POST to get the access token, just a HTTP GET with the values in the query string.